# How to use uninitialized data in GCC inline assembly

Tags: assembly, intel, inline-assembly

I want to use GCC inline assembly, Intel syntax.

Is there an equivalent for what I do in NASM:

```
myvar resb 1024
```

which reserves 1024 bytes memory at location `myvar`?
GCC does not seem to like it:

```
Error: no such instruction: `myvar resb 1024'
```

for

```
int main () {
    asm("myvar resb 1024");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're mixing C and inline assembly you should let the C compiler handle the memory allocation.  Declare your memory as `char myvar[1024]` and reference that from the inline assembly as needed.  You can probably access it directly but it would be best to pass it as an arg to `asm()` and let the compiler choose the addressing format for you.

Comment: So does that mean GCC will always ignore `resb`s, even if I write the assembly myself in an .s file into the proper region?

Comment: When you use GCC you're assembling with GAS which has different syntax than NASM (which you must be used to if you want `resb`).  If you put the right command (eg `.lcomm`) in the right section GAS will reserve space for you.  Check out:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html .  However, I think you would be better off doing the allocation in C for mixed code.